# How do I copy the content to new Word Document and replace the text in new Document

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, cpu-word

I am trying to read all text in word document, translated it and and Open in new document with translated text. I already copied the content to new document, How do I translate the current text by range and insert translate text in to correct range ?

Here what I am trying to implement.

```
    //Create new document
    var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    try
    {
       Document translatedDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();

       //Get content from existing doc
        var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Range oRange = doc.Content;


        //paste to new documnent
        translatedDoc.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType: WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);

        var paragraphs = doc.Paragraphs;
        foreach (Paragraph paragraph in paragraphs)
        {
            Range rng = paragraph.Range;
            string pText = paragraph.Range.Text;

            var translated = DocSentenseTranslate(pText);

            //How do i replace the translated text ?
                    
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng);
       }

     wordApp.Visible = true;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
     throw;
  }
```

Comment: Please forgive me if I am missing something. It seems unnecessary to copy and paste the original text into a new document if you have to “translate” each paragraph anyway. I would think a better approach would be to open the original doc for reading, create a new document for writing. Then, loop through each paragraph in the original document... get the string from the paragraph, then call the `DocSentenseTranslate(pText);` and add the returned string as a new paragraph into the new doc. An extra step may be needed since it is unclear what is returned from `DocSentenseTranslate(pText);`

Comment: Hi @JohnG Thanks. method returns the translate text of the paragraph. Can you give example for "open the original doc for reading, create a new document for writing. " and can we keep the format ( existing images..) ?

Comment: If you want to grab everything including pictures etc. Then I would suggest you “copy” the whole file first, then loop through the paragraphs, get the paragraph text, translate the text, then delete the old text and add the translated text. It is unknown how the doc is formatted etc., however, considering the text is getting translated, isn’t there the possibility that the new “translated” text may take up more (or less) space and possibly “change” the current text flow? I am just saying that by translating the text, I am confident more work may be necessary since the text flow “may” change.

Comment: Also, I am somewhat curious “why” you want to use interop for this. You are aware you can change the entire language in an existing word document from Word itself. Open the document, right click on an empty space and select “Translate.” You can choose between the “selected” text or the whole document. Is there some special translator you need to use?

Comment: @JohnG, yes exactly I have to integrate thirdparty API, need to do the same functionality does by MS translator. 
Thanks for your feedback. I am kind of new to VSTO, so can we create a exact copy of the word doc ? without copy paste

Comment: _”so can we create a exact copy of the word doc ? without copy paste”_ … sure… open the doc, then `SaveAs` a new doc.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG, will follow the flow you mention here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224954/discussion-between-sandun-tharaka-and-johng).

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it in your current example. I am pretty sure you can simply “replace” the “paragraph text” with the “translated text” … like…

```
paragraph.Range.Text = translated;
```

Below is my test such that the code opens the given file (`source`), saves the file to the give path-file name (`dest`), then loops through each paragraph in the document and replaces the text in the paragraph with translated text, then finally re-saves the new document. I did not post the “translate” method as you said you had a specific translator to use. Obviously, you would change that method to your method.

Also, a couple of notes, as can be seen in my code, I highly recommend you structure most `interop` methods in this fashion… using a `try/catch/finally`. This will help avoid “leaking” resources. All the code goes in the “try” portion. The “catch” portion to display any errors and the important “finally” portion to close the file and release the resources. The “finally” portion will ALWAYS execute, even if the code throws an exception.

In addition, it appears you may be running this code in a `BackgroundWorker`, this is fine, however you need to be careful and NOT use the UI which is in another thread. I have not tried this; however, I would guess you may run into problems if you attempt to execute…

```
wordApp.Visible = true;
```

in the background worker. It may work, and if it does, then go for it… this is just a heads up… that your background worker should NOT try and access any of the UI elements from the calling thread. I am guessing you may already know this.

Anyway, try the code below as it worked in my tests.

```
private void TranslateDoc(string source, string dest) {
  Word.Application wordApp = null;
  Word.Document myWordDoc = null;
  try {
    wordApp = new Word.Application();
    if (File.Exists(source)) {
      //wordApp.Visible = true;
      myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(source);
      myWordDoc.SaveAs2(dest);
      myWordDoc.Close();
      myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(dest);
      Word.Paragraphs paragraphs = myWordDoc.Paragraphs;
      string originalText;
      string replacementText;
      for (int i = 1; i <= paragraphs.Count; i++) {
        originalText = paragraphs[i].Range.Text;
        if (originalText != "\r") {
          replacementText = TranslateText(originalText);
          paragraphs[i].Range.Text = replacementText;
        }
      }
      myWordDoc.SaveAs2(dest);
      MessageBox.Show("File Created!");
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("Original File not Found!");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally {
    if (myWordDoc != null) {
      myWordDoc.Close();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myWordDoc);
    }
    if (wordApp != null) {
      wordApp.Quit();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage…

```
string sourceFileName = @"D:\Test\WordFiles\Translate1.docx";
string destFileName = @"D:\Test\WordFiles\Translate2.docx";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TranslateDoc(sourceFileName, destFileName);
}
```